# Maui migrated app iOS app icon not showing when deployed

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have a migrated Xamarin.Forms app in Maui on .Net 7.0.

For some reason the iOS app icon is not showing at all when deployed, as if it is not set.

I have it both in csproj and info.plist exactly as it was under Xamarin.Forms.

ios csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ImageAsset Update="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiocnset\icon[size].png">
         <Link>Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiocnset\icon[size].png</Link>
    </ImageAsset>
</ItemGroup>
```

info.plist:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiocnset</string>
```

But I don't see the icon when deployed.

Does anyone know how to handle the missing icon?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) way and you want to use your existing Xamarin Forms icons(png). You need to add `IPhoneResourcePrefix` in your `.cproj` to specify the path you want to use for iOS.

Example:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <IPhoneResourcePrefix>Platforms/iOS/Resources</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here, use `Platforms/iOS/Resources` path for resource and added existing `Assets.xcassets` into the `Resources` folder. No need to change existing plist `XSAppIconAssets` value.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can check document : [Add an app icon to a .NET MAUI app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android).

In your project file, the `<MauiIcon>` item designates the icon to use for your app. You may only have one icon defined for your app. Any subsequent `<MauiIcon>` items are ignored.

The icon defined by your app can be composed of a single image, by specifying the file as the Include attribute:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For more information, you can refer to the documentation above.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice. I am however trying to use the resources we have. I did not see anywhere in the documentation that we are forced to use svg in the new maui-icon format in order for us to migrate to maui. Is that a must? Do you have advice about solving the issue at hand?

Comment: Yes, you can use the images you have had, but some problems may arise for lower version of visual studio. And there is a known issue about this, you can check it here:[PNG Image set to Application Icon for MAUI Application loses transparency](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2564).

Comment: Since bitmap (non-vector) image formats aren't automatically resized by .NET MAUI in default, so we recommend that you use vector graphics, which will make your images better adapted to different devices.

Comment: That's all fine, but I can't find a single example of how to reuse existing xcassets from my xamarin.forms project, in my migrated maui solution with 3 projects still. Can you perhaps direct me to examples showing this?

Comment: Are the images different for each platform?

Comment: Yes, we have png images that adhere to Apple's requirements, sitting in the iOS project, under the assets.xcassets folder

Comment: Then you can check document : [Use a different icon per platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#use-a-different-icon-per-platform). You can add the Condition attribute to the `<MauiIcon>` item, and query for the specific platform.